# Apache has become unreachable on RHEL7

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, lamp, rhel7

I'm running a Magento install on RHEL7 on a EC2 instance.  Everything was working well and then all of a sudden my http requests stopped getting responses.  I restarted the instance and there was no change.  I can still ssh into the server.  Here are the contents of the apache error log:

```
[Mon Dec 15 20:20:56.907331 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1085] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 15 20:20:56.907894 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1085] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Dec 15 20:20:56.920284 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1085] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 15 20:20:56.920292 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1085] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

My understanding is that nothing in that log tells me why it isn't working.  What would be the next step to finding the issue?  Apache version is 2.4.6 and httpd.config syntax checks out.  My bet is the culprit is user permissions - how would I check to see if that is the issue?

Comment: Stopped getting responses how? Response hangs, immediately comes back but empty, etc..?

Comment: Hangs - the connection times out.  I can ping the server at the public IP address if I open the correct ports for that security group.

Comment: Have you checked disk is not full?

Comment: Yep.  Mostly free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was entirely elsewhere.  Apache was working just fine.  The error was somewhere after Magento's index.php file and there seems to be some type of problem with my PHP setup.  As soon as I requested another file from the /var/www/html directory Apache served it just like it should.  My bad for making such a basic mistake.